# Get Total Number of AppSync requests generated for certain period of time | AWS | APPSYNC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, appsync-apollo-client, aws-appsync-resolver

Is there a way to get the Total number of (appsync) api requests made to application for a certain time period?

I'm testing a module of application and it is generating requests. I want to calculate the total number of requests generated for all the time my module ran.

In appsync monitoring, I can see the graph. The way I understand it (i'm trying to learn, correct me if wrong) **it is showing the total number of requests system has got at each unit time.**

So, if it has a **peak** at certain unit of time, the next unit of time total requests (till now) are = **PEAK requests + requests at CURRENT Unit of time**.

So, for the graph below, total number of requests must be way more than 34k. right?

[image: graph]

Now my question is: **Can I calculate the total number of requests made to the system for this period of time**?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chart is currently set to show requests from the week, grouped in 5 minute buckets.  The total for a given period is the sum of the dots.

You can, of course, change the `5 minutes` dropdown to show fewer, bigger time buckets.

If that is not precise enough, you could enable request logging (`Settings > Logging` in the console) and use CloudWatch log insights to aggregate the individual log data.

Comment: I didn't note the time bracket. It makes much more sense now. Thanks